# Is there a good Python library that lets me generate a temporary S3 token, so that other people can upload to my S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is a temporary authentication token that can allow my mobile app to upload directly to S3.

The library should take the details of my Amazon account...and return a token.

I want the simplest library possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason you can't just use [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/)

Comment: How do I generate a temporary key?